# How should I loop/parse specific values from json object with lots of nested arrays?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I need to manipulate the data in [this JSON file](https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/YAHOO/INDEX_VIX.json).

I need to create two arrays. One with everything from the date column, and one with everything from the close column.

In other words, from each of the nested arrays in the data object, I need to pull out all the values at position [0] to create a new array then do the same for all values at position [4].

I saved down the JSON file to my server using:

```
file_put_contents("VIX.json", fopen("https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/YAHOO/INDEX_VIX.json?api_key=xxxx", 'r'));
```

What is the best approach for doing this? PHP or Javascript? Ultimately the two arrays will be used to create a [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/).

My initial thoughts are something like:

```
date = new Array();
var i, data;
for (i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++)
{
  date.push(dataset.data[i].something[0]);
}
```

None of the nested arrays have names which is currently confusing me. This is what im googling at the moment. Used `something` as a placeholder in these notes. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: SO will be able to help if you can show us an example of what you've tried and any issues you're having

Comment: added to the Q. a work in progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**in Javascript**

```
var date = [];
var list = json.dataset.data;
for(i in list)
   date.push(list[i][0]);
```

**in PHP**

You can try this

decoding json to be able to fetch the object in php
to browse a php object, the used operator is ->
once you reach the true array of position's set, 
read it by foreach

```
<?php

$o = file_get_contents("VIX.json");
$o = json_decode($o);

$date = [];
$list = $o->dataset->data;
foreach($list as $set)
{
    $date[] = $set[0];
    //printf("x: %f, y: %f, z: %f\n", $pos[1], $pos[2], $pos[3]);
}
```